# Hard Drive Ultra DMA CRC Error Count

Tags: ssd, hardware-failure, sata

I've read every single question related to this topic and really haven't gotten any answers.

These suggestions:

- Try different cable.
- Look if cable connector is connected good with connector on mainbord/harddisk.
- Try a different controller connection.

I've tried a different cable and used a different computer (which is a brand new build), and still get this error on multiple hard drives.

What exactly does this error mean? Does this happen to all hard drives over time? It's currently happening to my Samsung SSD 250, WD 2 TB, and my WD Green 500 GB. What is the deal. 2 have 1 error, and other has 4 errors. Is this actually an error.

MY SSD drive is my main operating system, and from time to time i get random blue screens. Could this be the cause of this?

[image]

Comment: I had this when I used a bad cable. Replace the cable and relax.

Comment: I replaced the cable as stated already. I'm relaxed

Comment: @Sickest - the count will not go away once the error occurs. So, changing the cable did the trick. Thus, going forward you have to monitor for increase. If you changed the cable, you will probably find that the count stays the same from here on out. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

CRC is a checksum that allows for detection of changes in the data the checksum was computed for. So for example a checksum is computed for a sector worth of data and then both are written to the drive. If we read back, we should get the same checksum and if not either the data or the checksum is incorrect.

On modern drives a more powerful type of error detection (and correction) is used; ECC.

Your error is not a checksum that was written to the drive, but one that is computed over data that will be send across a 'data path' so at the end of the path it can be determined if data was transferred without errors:

**The ultra DMA CRC error count** indicates problems with the transfer of data between the host and the disk. They can't be caused by software, and they don't indicate a problem with the disk itself. So personally I would reseat all of the drive cables and if the numbers continue to climb, then I'd try using different cables.

Cheers! :)