# Windows fails to start immediately after factory restore. Faulty hard drive?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot

After a factory restore from a recovery partition, Windows 7 fails to start, rebooting before it displays the splash screen.  I suspect a failing hard drive or SATA controller.

I'm now running [HDAT2](http://www.hdat2.com/) via [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/).  SMART showed bad values for:

- 0xC7: UltraDMA CRC Error Count

  - Value: 100 (Threshold 0)
  - Raw: 32532391 (and growing)
- 0xC8: Write Error Rate

  - Value: 100 (Threshold 0)
  - Raw: 134791835 (and growing)
- 0xBF: G-sense Error Rate

  - Value: 100 (Threshold 0)
  - Raw: 55

I seriously doubt that the laptop has ever been dropped — it probably never moved off of the desk — so the G-sense thing is weird.

[Some sources](https://superuser.com/a/868406/4086) claim that 0xC7 implies a problem with the controller or cable, not the drive.  But I never seem to have any problems booting off of a CD or the recovery partition.

I ran HDAT2's READ/WRITE/READ/COMPARE test on the Windows partition's sectors and, in five hours, got 5% through with zero errors.  A VERIFY test went 100% through with no errors.  I've also run MemTest86, MemTest86+, and various CPU stress tests, all with no errors.  The only test I've managed to get errors from is [Video Memory Stress Test CE](http://mikelab.kiev.ua/index_en.php?page=PROGRAMS/vmt_en), and I suspect that's just because it's detecting the amount of video memory incorrectly.  (256MB for the built-in Intel Graphics?)

Any way to tell if it's a hard drive error or a controller error?  Any reason to believe that it's anything else?

---

**Hardware**

- Dell Inspiron 3521
- Windows 7
- Toshiba MQ01ABF050 500 GB SATA hard drive

---

**Back story**, in case it helps:

I am helping my aunt with her 18 month old Dell Inspiron 3521 running Windows 7.  She asked me to help because it was running slowly.  I determined that there was a lot of malware installed and decided to reinstall.  (While researching the malware, I booted Kaspersky's recovery CD, after which Windows would no longer boot, in the same way it won't boot now.)  I found that I was able to boot into Dell's recovery partition and have it do a factory restore, so I did.

After the restore, I couldn't get Windows Update to work.  It just spun on "Scanning for Updates" for hours.  I finally discovered [Windows Update Client for Windows 7: June 2015](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3050265) and installed it manually.  After that, the scan completed in a reasonable amount of time and it installed a ton of updates.  It rebooted and installed a ton more.  Then it rebooted again and failed to start properly and booted into recovery mode.  (I wasn't paying close attention, so I didn't see the exact boot failure.)  The automated recovery tool said it wasn't able to do anything.

I tried to reboot again, and it still wouldn't boot into Windows.  It reboots before Windows even displays a splash screen.

I reinstalled from the factory image again, and it still failed to start, again rebooting before it even hit the Windows splash screen.  I reformatted the partition and reinstalled again, with the same results.  And this is where I started the question.

Comment: Sounds like hard drive failure is soon, install a new hard drive and clone the old drive to the new one.

Comment: @Moab: Do you have any basis for suspecting the hard drive and not the controller?  I can replace the laptop completely with something better for not that much more than replacing just the hard drive in this one.  (If I had a hard drive lying around I would try it, but I don't.)

Comment: Odds say it is the hard drive, no way to know for sure unless I can can put hands on it.